# PHP Date from different server

Tags: php, date, time

Our current hosting company is based in Canada so obviously their times are different to the UK.

Is there any way in PHP to display the Date/Time but get it from a different server if i specify the IP?

Comment: Using timezones would be a better idea

Comment: If you know the location of each of these servers, then why don't you manually input the time zones for each and echo them out? + Store the IP as an array for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`date_default_timezone_set` (see documentation)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function to set your actual script time to whatever you need

example for `Rome`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using timezones would be a better idea.

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s);
```